# What is a .java.in file?

Tags: java

I have found a repository that contains java code
but the files don't have the normal **.java** suffix,
but **.java.in**

Please what is that?

I have found it in the Kody repository ob Github

https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/tree/master/tools/android/packaging/xbmc/src/org/xbmc/kodi

Comment: Is it `.java.in` or `.java.it` ? And what kind of project is it? Could you share some source code or some build instructions? It could be that these are some kind of template files that get processed to give the actual `.java` source files...

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I have updated my question, is `.in` and here is the link https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/tree/master/tools/android/packaging/xbmc/src/org/xbmc/kodi

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember it means integration test. I think it is used by the Maven Failsafe Plugin https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/

This is just a possibility. It may be something else

Answer (score 1):

These `.in` files are processed by the [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html) system. The placeholders in the files of the form `@APP_NAME_LC@` will be replaced with the values of the variables with the respective name and the result is then written to a normal file without the `.in` extension.

The use for Java is somewhat uncommon.
The autoconf system is common in the *NIX world to cope with differences in system libraries for C and C++ as well as build tools.